# how to do if query in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to make a query in which if the query does not find records for the query not exist, then it looks to see if these codes are present in the array field. The join will go through the code c_oplmlp/c_serv

```
select distinct ocf.code_head_mo , cs.c_oplmp, r."name", ocf.code_state, rm2.name_short,
ocf.id_condition_mc 
from puomp.op_registry r 
join puomp.op_case_finish ocf on r.id_registry =ocf.id_registry 
join puomp.op_patient pt on ocf.id_patient =pt.id_patient 
join puomp.op_case sl on ocf.id_case_finish =sl.id_case_finish 
join puomp.op_case_ext cs on sl.id_case =cs.id_case
left join nsi.ref_mo rm2 on r.id_head_mo =rm2.id_mo 
where not exists(select * from lic_app_new lm
                left join ksg_p kp                  
where 
lm.fc_mo=ocf.code_head_mo 
and (lm.c_serv =cs.c_oplmp) if( (lm.c_serv !=cs.c_oplmp) then 
                                lm.c_serv=kp.smj_prof )
                                endif;
)
```

ksg_p table look like this

```
ksg_p
|---id
|---name
|---c_prof(same as c_serv)(main code)
|---smj_prof(related to c_prof)
```

The idea is if query does not find by main code(c_serv) it search by related codes. This is codes of illneses. Smj_prof contains related codes of illness code. For example ucler has a code of 3( witch is code of gastroenterology) and it has related codes of 9(therapy) and 10(pediatrics). It means that pacient can be treated in gastroenterology, therapy and pediatrics

Help pls i dont even had an idea of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

What if you need just add public. to SELECT options

example:

select distinct public.ocf.code_head_mo, public.cs.c_oplmp, ...etc...

Comment: No, it doesn't work still